# Trouble finding records whose attendance is .where <= current record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am looking to publish all records that have an attendance of less than or equal to (<=) the current record, but I'm struggling.

My model is...

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :attendances
    has_many :classes, :through => :attendances 

end

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :student
    validates :student_id, presence: true
    belongs_to :class
    validates :class_id, presence: true

end

class Class < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :attendances
    has_many :students, :through => :attendances    

end
```

I want to show against the current student all other students with an attendance of <= to them, but my calculation is wrong.

Logic is telling me it should be the following;

```
<% student_attend = @student.attendance.sum(:attend) %>

<% @student.attendance.where(:student_id=> :id).where("attend <= ?", student_attend).each do |att| %>

<%= att.name %>
```

...but not working, nor have the other derivations I have tried.

Would someone be kind enough to point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are selecting from the attendance table, what you want is to pull data from the student table joining with the attendance table for criteria, I can't test this right now but should look like this:

```
<% @student.joins(:attendance).where("attendance.attend <= ?", student_attend).each do |student| %>
```

I'm not sure if you need each students' attendance sum to be <= than student_attend, that would require a little bit of tweaking.